# How do I change the folder Eclipse exports libraries to?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, executable-jar

I have my project, say project Bob.  This project needs to be exported.
Project Bob needs libraries, so I need to export those too.  I do not, however,
wish to extract the libraries into Bob's jar itself.

When exporting with libraries in a folder next to the jar, the lib folder is called `Bob_lib`.  My question is simply how to make that folder into just `lib`.

I could rename the folder and update the manifest file, but that's a bit of a
hassle for every time I export.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use "FileSync" plugin for Eclipse to sync your JARs (or any other files) to the project export folder (or any required folder).

Please refer below URL for "FileSync" plugin for Eclipse:

http://andrei.gmxhome.de/filesync/

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you could check "save as ANT script" in the export dialog, and then edit the script and do the desired replacing.

Notice that all the paths within this script are *absolute*, in case you want to move/copy it to another folder.